# Laravel 5.6: Why does AJAX POST to Controller not show data load in Controller?

Tags: ajax, post, laravel-5.6

I have been working on this for hours,and not getting anywhere. Essentially, my Ajax call appears to be working well. I am pulling in form data from a view. I can see the XHR data when I look into Chrome Network. I have a status 200, and "OK". However, no matter what I do, I can not get any data to show in my controller. I have tested my route by commenting it out and sure enough I get an error, so that is positive. Also the XHR data shows the correct url as well. But even just a simple dd($request) inside the controller gives me nothing, not even an empty []. I have tried every option and Googled this to death. What am I doing wrong - Thanks !

**Abbreviated HTML**

```
<form action="" method="POST"  id="formData">
        <fieldset>
        {{ Form::hidden('customer_id',$customer[0]->id,['id'=>'customer_id'])}}
        {{ Form::hidden('lastname1',$customer[0]->lastname1,['lastname1'=>'lastname1'])}}
        {{ Form::hidden('reference',$quotation[0]->reference,['id'=>'reference'])}}
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

**AJAX**

```js
 $("#editsubmit").on('click', function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        var formData =$("#formData").serialize();
        var id = $("#reference").val();

        $.ajax({
            headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
            type: 'POST',
            contentType:'JSON',
            processData: false,
            url: '/save_edit/'+id,
            data: {
                "_method": 'POST',
                "result": formData,
            },

          
            error: function () {
                alert('there has been a system level error - please contact support')
            }
        });
    });
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('/save_edit/{id}','QuotationController@save_quote_edited');
```

**Controller**

```
 public function save_quote_edited(Request $request){

    dd(json_decode($request->getContent(), true));
}
```

Comment: I think that the click function should have `event` as incoming parameter. By the way, I'm having exactly the same problem and cannot solve it.

Answer (score 0):

To process forms you should not be calling `$request->getContent()` you should be calling `$request->all()` to get all parameters, `$request->get('foo')` or `$request->foo` to get a single parameter, or `$request->get(['foo','bar','baz')` to get multiple parameters.

And for bonus points if you used [Laravel's Form Request Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#form-request-validation) you could call `$request->validated()` and get only the parameters which passed the validation checks.

Comment: thanks for that. However, for some unknown reason my ajax call does not even open the controller. I can not get any output from the controller in any way.

Comment: Is the Ajax call hitting the API route, whereas you have the controller registered as a web route? In other words are you sure your route and controller are correctly aligned, try a `php artisan route:list` in the command line to check the route that the controller should respond to

Comment: I think you are right. my controller is set up as a web route from a guard perspective. So ... not too sure what to do. Create a new controller specifically for this function? Then set up the route inside api routes, and the new controller under a different api guard ? Is this right ? What's your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

Your route requires a parameter of "id" but you do not have that parameter in your controller method.

```
Route::post('/save_edit/{id}','QuotationController@save_quote_edited');
```

Try :

```
public function save_quote_edited(Request $request, $id){

    *** insert code here ***

}
```

Comment: thanks for that. I tried that, but it has not helped. I have however established two things: first that dd() ( die and dump) no longer will render in a Chrome based browser, nor Firefox. It is a well know bug. Therefore I am not seeing any pf the $request data come out when testing. Secondly, my real issue is that I am sending over a mutidimensional array in json and I am not decoding it properly inside Laravel. I have not yet figured out how to do that yet.